# Codeigniter Join multiple table & Sum

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

I have three tables on my Database. 
First table- insurance_policy, Second one- insurance_customer & third one- insurance_payments

I'm trying to get data from policy table with a specific date range, same time trying to pull customer information from customer table & finally trying to get payment information for that policy.

Here is the code so far-

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('insurance_policy');
$this->db->join('insurance_customer', 'insurance_customer.customer_id = insurance_policy.Customer_ID', 'left');
$this->db->join('insurance_payments', 'insurance_payments.Policy_Number = insurance_policy.Policy_ID', 'left');
$this->db->where('insurance_policy.Payment_Date >=', $from);
$this->db->where('insurance_policy.Payment_Date <=', $to);

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

I'm trying to get Sum of Amount column from payment table, instead of returning all records. Since payment data can be multiple with same policy id, i get multiple result of payment data like the result below. Instead I'm trying to get one result per policy id(no duplicate due to multiple payment of that policy id) & sum of amount from payment table for that policy.

Thanks in Advance.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Policy_ID] => 26
        [Policy] => 1234
        [Customer_ID] => 30
        [Effective_Date] => 06/08/2016
        [Expiration_Date] => 06/08/2017
        [Insurer] => Lorem
        [Billing] => Lorem
        [Agent] => Lorem
        [Notes] => Lorem
        [Mail_Date] => 
        [Callback_Date] => 
        [Contact_Date] => 
        [Type] => Lorem
        [Policy_Total] => 140
        [Commission_Amount] => 0
        [Brokerage_Fee] => 0
        [Insurance_Price] => 140
        [Payment_Date] => 06/08/2016
        [Cancellation_Date] => 
        [Paid_in_Full] => 0
        [customer_id] => 30
        [First_Name] => Lorem
        [Last_Name] => Lorem
        [Company_Name] => Lorem
        [Company_Type] => Lorem
        [EIN_Number] => 
        [Fee_License] => 1234
        [Address] => Lorem
        [City] => Lorem
        [State] => CA
        [Zipcode] => 12345
        [Phone] => 123-456-7890
        [Alt_Number] => 
        [Fax_Number] => 
        [Email] => user@hotmail.com
        [id] => 8
        [Policy_Number] => 26
        [Date] => 08/16/2017
        [Amount] => 400
        [status] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Policy_ID] => 26
        [Policy] => 1234
        [Customer_ID] => 30
        [Effective_Date] => 06/08/2016
        [Expiration_Date] => 06/08/2017
        [Insurer] => Lorem
        [Billing] => Lorem
        [Agent] => Lorem
        [Notes] => 
        [Mail_Date] => 
        [Callback_Date] => 
        [Contact_Date] => 
        [Type] => Lorem
        [Policy_Total] => 140
        [Commission_Amount] => 0
        [Brokerage_Fee] => 0
        [Insurance_Price] => 140
        [Payment_Date] => 06/08/2016
        [Cancellation_Date] => 
        [Paid_in_Full] => 0
        [customer_id] => 30
        [First_Name] => Art
        [Last_Name] => Lorem
        [Company_Name] => Lorem
        [Company_Type] => Lorem
        [EIN_Number] => 
        [Fee_License] => 55555
        [Address] => Lorem
        [City] => Lorem
        [State] => CA
        [Zipcode] => 12345
        [Phone] => 333-444-5555
        [Alt_Number] => 
        [Fax_Number] => 
        [Email] => user@hotmail.com
        [id] => 4
        [Policy_Number] => 26
        [Date] => 08/15/2017
        [Amount] => 200.10
        [status] => 1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
$this->db->select('SUM(insurance_policy.Policy_Total)');//changed
$this->db->from('insurance_policy');
$this->db->join('insurance_customer', 'insurance_customer.customer_id = 
insurance_policy.Customer_ID', 'left');
$this->db->join('insurance_payments', 'insurance_payments.Policy_Number = insurance_policy.Policy_ID', 'left');
$this->db->where('insurance_policy.Payment_Date >=', $from);
$this->db->where('insurance_policy.Payment_Date <=', $to);
$this->db->group_by("Policy_ID");//added

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```